# Why the comparison result are not as expected?

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparison, unsigned-integer

Could you explain why the following code give these result?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    unsigned int y = 1;
    if (x > y)
        std::cout << "true";
    else
        std::cout << "false";
}
```

**Output =** `true` but why ?

Comment: please one question per question. They are related, but still 2 seperate questions

Comment: Comparison between signed and unsigned.

Comment: Read about [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: `x > y` becomes `static_cast<unsigned int>(x) > y`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you, I will read about this topic

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks i got it :)

Comment: fwiw, compilers warn about it. With the "right" settings the code does not compile https://godbolt.org/z/nPTEbWWYf. Frankly, if you had read the warning you would already know part of the "why". Don't ignore compiler warnings!

Comment: @molbdnilo Does the compiler always cast the type of the left operand of the > operator to the type of the right operand? is this a rule

Comment: left or right isnt the point. Read the link Ted provided you above

Comment: This is why C++20 introduced utilities for mixed comparisons https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is a implicit conversion from `int` to `unsigned int`, which happens to take place in the following manner.

```
int x = -a;
unsigned int y = x; //As far as y can hold only positive values, 
//it now holds UINT_MAX - (a + 1)
```

Where `UINT_MAX` is a macro which is defined as the maximum value `unsigned int` can hold.

In your case `x` is converted to `UINT_MAX`, which is obviously larger than 1

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that this code:

```
    int x = -1;
    unsigned int y = 1;

    bool result = x > y;
```

is converted to:

```
    int x = -1;
    unsigned int y = 1;

    bool result = operator>(x, y);
```

There are two operator> functions defined:

```
bool operator>(int, int);
bool operator>(unsigned int, unsigned int);
```

But you're calling `operator>(int, unsigned int)`. So compiler has converted your signed int to unsigned int and then called `operator>(unsigned int, unsigned int)` which has resulted in a bug.

The standard way to avoid this is to turn on compiler warnings. You can use -Wconversion warning that will warn you about this specific issue, or even better pass -Wall to turn on all warnings.

To fix the bug in the code you can explicitly tell the compiler how to convert the arguments to the comparison operator

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    unsigned int y = 1;
    if (x > static_cast<int>(y))
        std::cout << "true";
    else
        std::cout << "false";
}
```

But be careful with this as it can still result in a bug if your unsigned int is larger than the number that can fit into int. The safest solution is if you can make it so that both of the variables are the same type to begin with.